# Pass NULL in a list in prolog at terminal

Tags: prolog

How can I pass NULL/No value in prolog at terminal while the list is read?
I tried:
`_` but it is for a value which exists but we do not care about it.

Comment: there is a special atom indicating the empty list: `[]`

Comment: try Ctrl-D. or Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Need a little context here. Are you wanting to continue to read items into the list after you give it a null for one of the values? Perhaps you could show your list-reading code?

Comment: What do you mean with *while the list is read*?